# closed and bounded form

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

I have this problem, 
Let $\omega$ a closed $1$ form in $\mathbb{R^{2}}\setminus {0} $ such that $\omega$ restricted to the set $D$ is bounded with $D=\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R} \text{ such that }\left | x \right |<r\right \}$ Is it right that $\omega$ is exact? Proof or counter example.

Help, thanks!

Comment: Should your definition of $D$ include $0 < |x|$? Or am I missing something; seems as if $\omega$ isn't actually defined on all of the set you described as $D$.

Comment: Yes, de definition of $D$ include $0< \left | x \right |$